# Android Studio 2.2 for Mac Error unknown property 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, macos, android-studio-2.2

I upgraded to Android Studio 2.2 yesterday since it's made available in the stable channel. An app that I had working properly in AS v2.1.3 now results in the following error whenever I try to Debug/Run the app.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.  Could not get unknown
>   property 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' for project ':app' of type
>   org.gradle.api.Project

If I change Gradle Plugin version to 2.1.3 in `build.gradle`(Project), everything works again and I can run/debug the app without issue.

I have searched on SO and found similar posts but none of the suggested solutions worked for me so far.  I'm developing on a Mac and using  the embedded JDK shipped with 2.2.

Comment: You changed Gradle to 2.1.3 or the "Gradle Plugin" to 2.1.3? They are different things

Comment: I changed the Gradle plugin version to 2.1.3 in project level build.gradle:  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

Comment: I believe that needs to be 2.2.0 and the Gradle version must be 2.14.1 or higher. You might also want to [edit] your question to include your Gradle files

Comment: My grade version is set to 2.14.1.  If I change plugin version to 2.2.0, then I get the error mentioned in my post.  Changing it to 2.1.3 seems to be the only way to not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the $PROJECT_HOME/.gradle directory after changing the gradle plugin 2.2.0, and clean and build again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see a .gradle directory in $PROJECT_HOME.

Comment: Well, Please try to remove the directory if thare is a .gradle directory in $HOME.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my Mac to Sierra and now everything is working fine.  I no longer get any error when I run/debug app on Android devices.  I'm using Android Studio 2.2 with Gradle plug-in 2.2.0.

So for anyone experiencing similar issues with Android Studio 2.2 and Yosemite, try upgrading your OS and see it resolves the issue.  Good luck.